# How to achieve the metro user area in WPF?

Tags: wpf, microsoft-metro

http://ledfrog.com/uploads/2011/06/zune-sw-screenshot-client-mossyroc.jpg

I want to have my user be able to login and access his profile pretty much like what is shown in that zune software screenshot in the upper right corner below the minimize/maximize/close buttons.

I already have the metro window setup thanks to [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/) library. Ive got myself a good metro-looking icon for when the user (Which is done in XAML thanks to Syncfusion's Metro Studio) has yet to login and i can login users easily. 
The problem i am facing right now is that the icon is done in XAML, but the picture for each user is in a remotely-stored bitmap. Is there a control that can host XAML or bitmaps on the fly? or do i have to rasterize the icon into plain png? Also, is there a way that i can store the XAML making up the icon in another file so i don't have to embed it into my window's XAML file?

On a sidenote, i'd prefer not to rasterize the icon to avoid pixelation.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

Using the App.xaml ResourceDictionary entry, i can store the XAML generated by the tool, then use a rectangle, set its fill property to a visualbrush that has its visual property set to {StaticResource xxx} where xxx is the name i put on the ResourceDictionary. After the user logs in, i just replace the visual property  of the brush to a image pointing to the url of the user's avatar.

Problem solved.